# Software/API for Arabic text summarization

Tags: nlp

Are there any text summarization softwares for Arabic. By text summarization i mean the important sentences to be extracted from the entire document.Basically i'm looking for an arabic summarizer which reduces the number of words to about (15-20%) but still preserves the main point as far as possible.

The software will be run on Ubuntu, ideally i would like to call it with a java API

Could'nt find any opensource or paid softwares with simple google search. It will be very helpful if you could point me towards some softwares.

Edit: I just found a software called essential-mining are there any other similar softwares

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: If you don't mind programming your own rules, then there is [Open Text Summarizer](http://libots.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to do that. It can be installed on Ubuntu using ``sudo apt-get install libots0``

Comment: @Timmy, thanks for the suggestion but on checking the xml file of OTS found that Arabic is not these among the languages. Would it still work even if the language is not mentioned.

Comment: @user6971 I can't test it since I'm not familiar with the language, but I can't see why it wouldn't work. Perhaps you could email the authors. Their contact information is on the [website](http://libots.sourceforge.net/). Izzy is right, please edit the question with the details you added in the comments to make it easier for future reference.

Comment: @user6971 Ideas: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/710/843

Comment: @Timmy, Thanks, I'll check up libots and email the authors.